# Basic application of category theory to data science

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, machine-learning, linear-regression, natural-transformations

Linear regression is the algorithm that, given a set of vectors ${\bf x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^p$, and a set of targets $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$, returns a vector ${\bf w} \in \mathbb{R}^p$ minimizing the summed prediction error $\sum_i ({\bf x}_i\cdot{\bf w} - y_i)^2$.

Ridge regression is the algorithm that instead returns a vector  ${\bf w} \in \mathbb{R}^p$ minimizing the penalized error function $\lambda |{\bf w}|^2 + \sum_i ({\bf x}_i\cdot{\bf w} - y_i)^2$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is a parameter of the algorithm.

Intuitively, it seems that linear regression operates when ${\bf x}_i$ lives in a vector space, while ridge regression operates when ${\bf x}_i$ lives in a Euclidean space. More specifically, given an invertible matrix ${\bf M} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$, if we transform ${\bf x}_i \mapsto  {\bf M x}_i$, then  the linear regression solution transforms as ${\bf w} \mapsto {{\bf M}^{-1}}^T {\bf w}$. However for ridge regression, this only works if $\bf M$ is orthogonal.

How can one express this formally in the language of categories, functors, and natural transformations?

**UPDATE**: I think I have an answer. It is too long for this page, written up [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.02072).

Answer (score 3):

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10455) by Fong, Spivak et al. offers an overview of learning algorithms from a categorical perspective. It might be applicable to your case.

Comment: Thanks! It looks interesting, but doesn't seem to address this specific point.